Mac Appstore upload ends with error: Bundle's info.plist features an unexpected CFBundleExecutable key
My MacOS application has been regularly notarized for 12 weeks to allow people test the beta version, without any problem. Now the application is ready for Appstore submission.
Unfortunately, the uploading process ends with an error: "Bad CFBundleExecutable. Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in the nested bundle ApplicationHelp [fr.application.pkg/Payload/Application.app/Contents/Resources/ApplicationHelp.help] property list file."
In the ApplicationHelp target, no CFBundleExecutable key is set. But if I read the Info.plist of the built help bundle, I can see that such key has been added during the build process. What can explain the presence of this key that seems to create the error when trying to upload the application package to the Appstore?
The keys set in the help bundle info.plist are:
HPDBookAccessPath
HPDBookIndexPath
HPDBookTitle
HPDBookType
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
CFBundleIdentifier
CFBundleSignature
CFBundleVersion
CFBundlePackageType
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion

Using Xcode 15.2 on Sonoma, application built for MacOS ≥ 12 (Apple Silicon only)
Thanks
